# Karma Firefox Doesn't Work With HTTPS

Tags: node.js, firefox, ssl, https, karma-runner

When I run Karma tests they fail as Firefox (as ran by Karma) won't except my certificate (i'm using https).

I'm using Karma to run integration tests on a NodeJs Firefox add-on. I'm testing it on my localhost machine using XAMPP's Apache. I've created ssl local keys, configured Apache to use the keys and when i'm trying it manually everything looks good. The problem only appears when Karma runs a FF profile. I tried installing the certificate globally on all profiles but that wasn't an option.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding the localhost certificate into Firefox's certificate store?

Comment: Yes, the trouble here is that certificates are added per FF profile. Karma runs a clean profile so it doesn't help.
FF (via Karma) wouldn't have known the add-on i'm trying to test installed on account of the clean profile so i have to config Karma to load the .xpi file.

Comment: I was hoping someone would have a way to config Karma to load the SSL keys OR setting up some kind of a global FF user.